# ns2 mpolsr compilation error for wsn

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile, ns2

I am trying to compile the `mpolsr` patched `ns-2.29` in `Linux Mint`  with `gcc-4.7`. I am getting the following error:

```
trace/cmu-trace.o: In function `MPOLSR_pkt::access(Packet const*)':
cmu-trace.cc:(.text._ZN10MPOLSR_pkt6accessEPK6Packet[_ZN10MPOLSR_pkt6accessEPK6Packet]+0x7): undefined reference to `MPOLSR_pkt::offset_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ns] Error 1
```

I am finding that the `cmu-trace.cc` file includes the correct header. I tried t add the cc file which has the definition of the offset function but no success. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using `ns-2.29_mpolsr.rar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ns-2.29_mpolsr.rar` file is broken, in that the authors of `mpolsr` only changed the `Makefile`, but not the `Makefile.in`. Thus, when you run the `./configure`, you will erase the changes in the `Makefile`.

These are the steps you need to do for compiling it:

**1. Edit the `Makefile.in`:**

Add the directories `olsr` and `mpolsr` to the `INCLUDES` variable. It should look like this:

```
INCLUDES = \
        -I. \
        @V_INCLUDES@ \
        -I./tcp -I./sctp -I./common -I./link -I./queue \
        -I./adc -I./apps -I./mac -I./mobile -I./trace \
        -I./routing -I./tools -I./classifier -I./mcast \
        -I./diffusion3/lib/main -I./diffusion3/lib \
        -I./diffusion3/lib/nr -I./diffusion3/ns \
        -I./diffusion3/filter_core -I./asim/ -I./qs \
        -I./diffserv -I./satellite \
        -I./wpan -I./olsr -I./mpolsr
```

Add the object files of `mpolsr` to the `OBJ_CC` variable. You should add a line like this (the one in the middle is the new one):

```
        olsr/OLSR.o olsr/OLSR_state.o olsr/OLSR_rtable.o olsr/OLSR_printer.o \
        mpolsr/MPOLSR.o mpolsr/MPOLSR_state.o mpolsr/MPOLSR_m_rtable.o mpolsr/MPOLSR_printer.o mpolsr/MPOLSR_rtable.o\
        common/ns-process.o \
```

If you are using a new version of `gcc`, you should also add the `-fpermissive` directive, otherwise it will fail to compile. To do this, change the `.cc.o:` directive to this:

```
.cc.o:
        @rm -f $@
        $(CPP) -fpermissive -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $*.cc
```

**2. Make the configure script executable**

In the `ns-2.29_mpolsr` directory, run

```
chmod +x configure
```

**3. Run the configure script**

Depending on the allinone version of ns, you run something like this:

```
./configure --with-otcl=$PWD/../otcl-1.13/ --with-tclcl=$PWD/../tclcl-1.19/
```

The above version numbers are for `ns-allinone-2.34`

**4. Make**

In the same directory run

```
make -j100
```

I checked the above with `gcc-4.6.3`, but it should also work with `gcc-4.7`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not expect such a detailed answer that too so fast. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked fantastically. But I am not not able to upvote I have lesser points.